# Is there a way to import a PDF into Inkscape with characters from the unicode supplementary planes?

Tags: unicode, inkscape, poppler

When a PDF is imported into Inkscape, any Unicode code point with more than 4 digits has the leading digits removed and displays as a 4 digit code point. For example, a math italic capital B () is U+1D435. But when a PDF with said character is imported into inkscape it becomes a Korean syllable (퐵) which is U+D435.

Somewhere in the import process some of the unicode information has been lost. Is there any way to fix this?

I don't know enough about the underlying issues to do much about the programming that is going on.

The issue is easily replicated by putting a text character with a 5-digit code point into an Inkscape file, saving it as a PDF, and then importating the PDF back into the inkscape file. The character will have changed.

Comment: Have you tried to use the new PDF importer from Inkscape 1.3-alpha?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. 
Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: I tried 1.3, and sadly it gives them same result.